# My prompt message not working in mips program

Tags: mips

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89CjO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57dl0.jpg)
write a program that asks the user to input a string (or no more than 50 characters) Your program should then output the length of the string. The string length should e determined using a separate function strlen that will accept the address of the string and return its length.

What does it mean when attempt to execute non - instruction and a unknown syscall 0

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: "*What does it mean when attempt to execute non - instruction and a unknown syscall 0*" — the code you've shown doesn't have any syscalls.  So, you have two or more separate issues, that here should be separate question posts, if you can't solve them individually by searching.